# Error "syntax unexpected '='" In Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax

I have the following `code`:

```
def medi_interaction regex1, regex2, min_abstand
  return_value=0
  self.medications.each do |m1|
    if m1.medi.atc ~= regex1
      self.medications.each do |m2|
        if m2.medi.atc ~= regex2 && m2.date-m1.date < min_abstand
          return_value++
        end
      end
    end
  end
  return return_value
end
```

For some reason, I'm getting an error that I can't fix. Can you help me with that?

**Error**:

```
Syntax _syntax error, unexpected '='_ and _unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting keyword_end_
```

Comment: In addition to @Jacob's point about the malformed matching operator, there's no auto-increment in ruby: `return_value++`.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex check looks off. Try `=~` instead of `~=`.